# What type of encoding is it?

Tags: encryption, encoding, utf-8, decode

I don't know what type of encoding is it.
Dose any body know it?

```
<encrypted>
GE4dGgsGABAaSU9SRUIEGwsOHEJJQ04NAAQJAAIOGwpPRV9DTgscHAAADgwKSERFQgYPCAAaERZE SVRPTwwLABsLCwEHCQZOQk9PBAYLAAsZDQgADR1JT1JFQhYHAgALDgAHTkJPTxcEAQsHGxtCRVlJ SRwJAwBERU5IDgoKRElUT08SDA1ISRI= 
</encrypted>
```

line one decode base64

```
\u0018N\u001d\u001a\v\u0006\0\u0010\u001aIOREB\u0004\u001b\v\u000e\u001cBICN\r\0\u0004\t\0\u0002\u000e\u001b\nOE_CN\v\u001c\u001c\0\0\u000e\f\nHDEB\u0006\u000f\b\0\u001a\u0011\u0016D
```

Comment: Looks like Base64-encoded data (possibly several separate parts). Other than that it's hard, if not impossible, to say. The best clues are probably in the context, of which you've shared nothing. If it is indeed encrypted then there's probably (hopefully) nothing you can do with it without the right key.

Comment: @Biffen Sure looks like base64 ... The two space bytes are consistent with Python docs "The legacy interface ... adds newlines every 76 characters as per RFC 2045" then somebody replaced newlines by spaces. Removing the spaces allows it to pass base64.b64decode(strg, validate=True). However the resultant bytes look like gobbledegook.

Comment: @Sinoheh What is the relevance of tagging with utf-8 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    byte[] bytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary("CEwcBxcZHAAYSFJOWl4UGQoTAF1VU0wMHRgWHBIMGhdTWkNTTAoBAB8cHg4LVVhaXhYNCR0GDgpU S1VSUxMXEBkKFh0YFRZMQ1JTGxobAgoEERccHR9IUk5aXgYFAx0XERwXTENSUwgYEQkGBgddWUlL SAEVHBxUR09VEhUWVEtVUlMNEB1KSA8=");
    String pass = "Username";
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        bytes[i] ^= (byte)pass.charAt(i % pass.length());
        System.out.print((char)bytes[i]);
    }

}
}
```